# Adding find contents to array

Tags: bash, find

I've currently got a script that generates R commands based on the output of find

```
#!/bin/bash
PATHX="/path/to/my/files"
find "${PATHX}" -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "*.csv" | while read d; do
FN=$(echo -n "${d}" | cut -d/ -f5 | cut -d. -f1)
echo "${FN}<-read.csv(\"${PATHX}/${FN}.csv\",header=TRUE)"
# <snip> etc .etc. etc.
echo "${FN}_2y<-tail(${FN}_log,730)"
done
```

This works great. But I've got one problem with one R command :

```
df<-data.frame(list,of,columns,goes,here)
```

I can't figure out how I can integrate this into the find/while above, namely I need to output a list of *${FN}_2y* into the data.frame() function.

So for example, assume my script outputted :

- a_2y
- b_2y
- c_2y

I need to end up with  df<-data.frame(a_2y,b_2y,c_2y)

Clarification further to question in comments, I only need one instance of data.frame, right at the very end once the all the csv inputs have been parsed in.

Comment: does the `data.frame` output need to show up inside the `while` loop after the `tail` line? because that loop will only see one line of output from `find` at a time.

Comment: @JeffSchaller no.  I only need to output one instance of data.frame, right at the end.

Comment: if I'm understanding your script correctly, it's echoing `R` commands, and not outputting "a_2y" & etc. The a,b,c parts are apparently base elements of some CSV filenames. Are we trying to update your existing script or write a separate one?

Comment: @JeffSchaller sorry for the confusion. The script works great, the script is outputting what I say in the example, I was just using a,b,c as substitute for the variables that originate from the input file names.   All I need is the one last bit of the script, right at the end, that creates the data.frame command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sort of thing is easier to do in `awk` or `perl` than in a shell script (although if you're using a `sh` like bash `which` supports arrays, it's a bit easier than if using a `sh` without arrays. You still have far more complications with quoting and globbing or expansion where you don't want it in a shell script than you do in `perl` or `awk`)

For example:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;

my $pathx='/path/to/my/files';

my $dh;
my @frames=();

# get list of .csv files from $pathx
opendir($dh, $pathx) || die "can't open directory '$pathx': $!\n";
my @csvfiles = grep { /\.csv$/ && -f "$pathx/$_" } readdir($dh);
closedir($dh);

foreach my $f (@csvfiles) {
   my @fields=split(/\./,$f);
   my $fn=$fields[@fields-2];   # perl array indices start from 0, not 1.

   printf '%s<-read.csv("%s",header=TRUE)'."\n", $fn, "$pathx/$f";
   # <snip> etc .etc. etc.
   printf '%s_2y<-tail(%s_log,730)'."\n", $fn, $fn;

   push @frames,"${fn}_2y";
}

print "df-<data.frame(", join(',',@frames), ")\n";
```

NOTE: you can use the `File::Find` module instead of a simple `readdir()` if you need directory recursion.

Sample output (with files `a.csv`, `b.csv`, and `c.csv`):

```
a<-read.csv("/path/to/my/files/a.csv",header=TRUE)
a_2y<-tail(a_log,730)
b<-read.csv("/path/to/my/files/b.csv",header=TRUE)
b_2y<-tail(b_log,730)
c<-read.csv("/path/to/my/files/c.csv",header=TRUE)
c_2y<-tail(c_log,730)
df-<data.frame(a_2y,b_2y,c_2y)
```

or with `awk`:

NOTE: awk doesn't have a `join()` function so I had to write one.  `awk` doesn't have a `readdir()` function either, so it's easiest to just pipe the output of `find` into it (write a wrapper `sh` script to do that if necessary).

```awk
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN {
  FS="[./]";
  delete A; # has side-effect of defining A as an array
};   

# i isn't an argument to this function, it's a local variable.
# in awk, extra whitespace separates function args from declaration
# of local variable(s)

function join(array,sep,       i) {     
  result=array[1];     # awk array indices start from 1
  for (i=2;i<=length(array);i++) result = result sep array[i];
  return result;
};

# main code block, run on every input line
{
  fn=$(NF-1);
  printf "%s<-read.csv(\"%s\",header=TRUE)\n", fn, $0;
  # <snip> etc .etc. etc.
  printf "%s_2y<-tail(%s_log,730)\n", fn, fn;
  A[length(A)+1] = sprintf("%s_2y",fn);
};

END {
  print "df-<data.frame(" join(",",A) ")";
}
```

save as, e.g., `myscript.awk`, make it executable with `chmod` and run as:

```
find "${PATHX}" -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "*.csv" | ./myscript.awk
```

Output is identical to the `perl` version.

Finally, the same algorithm in bash:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

PATHX="/path/to/my/files"

declare -a frames=()
# get list of .csv files and store in array csvfiles.
csvfiles=( $(find "$PATHX" -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*.csv' ) )

function join() {
  local sep result i
  sep="$1" ; shift
  result="$1" ; shift

  for i in "$@" ; do result="$result$sep$i" ; done
  printf '%s' "$result"
}

for f in "${csvfiles[@]}" ; do
  fn=$(basename "$f" '.csv')

  printf "%s<-read.csv(\"%s\",header=TRUE)\n" $fn $f;
  # <snip> etc .etc. etc.
  printf "%s_2y<-tail(%s_log,730)\n" $fn $fn;

  frames+=( "${fn}_2y" )
done

echo 'df-<data.frame('$( join ',' "${frames[@]}" )')';
```

This avoids a `while read` loop which is almost always the worst possible way to process a series of lines in a shell script.   Use `awk` or `perl` or `sed` or a `for` loop around an array - anything to avoid using a `while read` loop.

Comment: Wow ! Thanks for this !  And especially thanks for pointing out the more sensible way to do it in Perl !

Answer (score 2):

You can collect the names into a variable `fns` and echo this at the end. Since you have a pipe you need to keep the variable in the same subshell as the while/do/done. `${fns:1}` is a substring of the variable, dropping the initial extra comma.

```
#!/bin/bash
PATHX="/path/to/my/files"
find "${PATHX}" -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "*.csv" |
(   fns=
    while read d; do
        FN=$(echo -n "${d}" | cut -d/ -f3 | cut -d. -f1)
        echo "${FN}<-read.csv(\"${PATHX}/${FN}.csv\",header=TRUE)"
        # <snip> etc .etc. etc.
        echo "${FN}_2y<-tail(${FN}_log,730)"
        fns+=",${FN}_2y"
    done
    echo "df<-data.frame(${fns:1})"
)
```